# how to use broadcast receiver with service

Tags: android

how can i use broadcast receiver and service both of them, provided that app install on external storage. i programmed it but just run on internal storage device because i want when device rebooted service run instead start activity

my activity :

```
 public class FirstClass extends Activity 
 {
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
       public void run()
       {
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
        startActivity(new Intent(FirstClass.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
       }
    },5000);
  }
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////
 }
```

my broadcast receiver :

```
 public class BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn extends BroadcastReceiver {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
  context.startService(startServiceIntent);
   }
 }
```

i added :

```
<service
    android:name="com.dariran.MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
</service>
<receiver android:name="com.dariran.BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn"
android:enabled="true">
  <intent-filter android:priority="1">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action  android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

to appliation tag on Manifest.xml and 
i added this code to my service class to put a filter to recognize the external storage but don't work again :(

```
 @Override
 public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
 try {

 IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE);
 filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE);
 BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiverOnTurnedOn();
 registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

 } catch (Exception e) {
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />" make the application cant be moved to SD card?

Comment: what you mean? please help me because i'm trying to solve this problem about 7 days :(

Comment: What do you mean by " just run on internal storage"?

Comment: it's mean is if my app install on my internal storage (devices memory) it work fine but if the app install on external storage (added memory) it not work when device reboot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html#ShouldNot):

> In order for your application to consistently behave as expected, you should not allow your application to be installed on the external storage if it uses any of the following features...
>
> Broadcast Receivers listening for "boot completed"
> The system delivers the ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast before the external storage is mounted to the device. If your application is installed on the external storage, it can never receive this broadcast.

Quoting elsewhere in [the documentation, this time for `ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE) :

> The extra data EXTRA_CHANGED_UID_LIST contains a list of uids of packages whose availability changed. Note that the packages in this list do not receive this broadcast.

Hence, you will need to set up your app to not be installed on external storage.

Comment: i saw similar softwares that installed on external storage and be active when device reboot (their service)

Comment: @soheila: Services that you start up at boot time, with the plan on having them run forever, are an anti-pattern on Android. Hence, I would recommend that you focus instead on removing the need for starting the service at boot time. Also, please understand that few devices offer installation to external storage anymore, as most Android 3.0+ devices no longer need it.